# SQL Logic for generating new column based Matching field values

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

```
Input:
CUST TAX_TYPE 
a      TIN    
a      TIN    
a      SSN    
b      TIN    
b      TIN     
b      TIN    
c      SSN    
c      SSN    
c      null
```

```
Output:
CUST TAX_TYPE VALID 
a      TIN     n
a      TIN     n
a      SSN     n
b      TIN     y
b      TIN     y 
b      TIN     y
c      SSN     n
c      SSN     n
c      null    n
```

If same CUST has more than one TAX_TYPE, I should mark it as 'n' else if the same CUST has the same tax_type I should mark as 'y' in the VALID column. Can any one suggest the optimized spark-sql or standard sql (so that I can convert to spark sql query) logic query for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Use `case` and window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(TAX_TYPE) over (partition by cust) = max(tax_type) over (partition by cust) and
                  count(*) over (partition by cust) = count(tax_type) over (partition by cust)
             then 'y' else 'n'
        end) as valid
from t;
```

The second condition is validating that there are no `NULL` values.

Comment: Thank you for the logic, it eliminated the joins we are using right now to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `when-otherwise` to achieve desired output

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

scala> var df =Seq(("a", "TIN" ), ("a", "TIN" ), ("a", "SSN" ), ("b", "TIN" ), ("b", "TIN" ), ("b", "TIN" ), ("c", "SSN" ), ("c", "SSN" ), ("c","null")).toDF("cust","tax_type")

scala> df.withColumn("valid",when(size(collect_set(col("tax_type")).over(Window.partitionBy(col("cust")).orderBy(col("cust"))))>1,"N").otherwise("Y")).orderBy("cust").show()
+----+--------+-----+
|cust|tax_type|valid|
+----+--------+-----+
|   a|     TIN|    N|
|   a|     SSN|    N|
|   a|     TIN|    N|
|   b|     TIN|    Y|
|   b|     TIN|    Y|
|   b|     TIN|    Y|
|   c|     SSN|    N|
|   c|     SSN|    N|
|   c|    null|    N|
+----+--------+-----+
```

It will avoid all the min/max calculations for each row.